# dynamic_reconfigure with large parameter sets

Tags: ros, parameter, dynamic-reconfigure

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From looking at dynamic_reconfigure it seems that 'sub-namespaces' (next best term that came to my mind) for parameters are not supported. My scenario involves a robot with quite a few parameters on a per joint basis. So essentially, there are PID gains and multiple more parameters per joint. It would be natural to have those sorted like 'joint0/p_gain','joint0/d_gain'; 'joint1/p_gain','joint1/d_gain' etc. Is it possible to achieve something like this with dynamic_reconfigure or another option?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10642/dynamic_reconfigure-with-large-parameter-sets/) by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on ROS Answers with karma: 24361 on 2011-07-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Right now, there's no support in dynamic_reconfigure for sub-namespaces. However, this is a feature that's under development and should land in F-Turtle. We tried to get it in for electric, but pushed a bit to late and need to test things more to guarantee stability. If you're interested in trying things out, you might want to check out the review page for the feature: http://www.ros.org/wiki/dynamic_reconfigure/Reviews/7-1-11_groups.

---

Originally posted by [eitan](https://answers.ros.org/users/107/eitan/) with karma: 2743 on 2011-07-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1